# let nicedit allow iframes

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

if a users types:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/8FozVVP72Qk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

it becomes:

```
&lt;iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/8FozVVP72Qk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;
```

The code is shown instead of being interpreted.

So as long the nicedit documentation is old and not very complete, i thought i just replace those values,

I could use replace() function, but is there a function for this format conversion?

This is how i am getting the value:

```
$('body').on('submit','#new_blog',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var textarea = $(this).find('textarea').val();
   var valueWithIframeSupport = textarea.replace('&lt;','<').replace('&gt;','>');
   /* This is what i had in mind but itdoesnt really seems an option*/
});
```

thanks

Comment: That doesn't seem like a viable solution as it leaves nicedit open to code injection. I'm not even sure that's an issue for you. That being said, I'd imagine replacing all instances of `<iframe>` with `<video>` (for HTML5 support) and falling back to `<object>` for older browser support.

Answer (score 1):

try [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method:

```
var s = '&lt;iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/8FozVVP72Qk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt';
$('#elem').html(s)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4tW2u/3/

Comment: so $(this).html($(this).val()) ?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet yes, you can try that.

Comment: Actually i don't need to apply the html to any element. i am trying to get it as string. Tried with return textarea.val().html() but that's not a function